# How to turn this method into a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm training using tensorflow tfrecords, here are the methods/functions that handle the data:

reading function:

```
def read_tfr(tf_record_file, classes_file, feature_map, max_boxes,
         classes_delimiter='\n', new_size=None):
    text_init = tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(
        classes_file, tf.string, 0, tf.int64, -1, delimiter=classes_delimiter)
    class_table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(text_init, -1)
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(tf_record_file)
    dataset = files.flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
    default_logger.info(f'Read TFRecord: {tf_record_file}')
    return dataset.map(
        lambda x: read_example(x, feature_map, class_table, max_boxes, new_size))
```

dataset:

```
def initialize_dataset(self, tf_record, batch_size):
    dataset = read_tfr(tf_record, self.classes_file, get_feature_map(), self.max_boxes)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=128)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (
        transform_images(x, self.input_shape[0]),
        transform_targets(y, self.anchors, self.masks, self.input_shape[0])))
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset
```

then I call `model.fit()` in the following way:

```
history = self.training_model.fit(training_dataset,
                                  epochs=epochs,
                                  callbacks=callbacks,
                                  validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

This works perfectly fine for small datasets however, when I'm training on large datasets, the training sooner or later is killed by the oom killer so I thought of using a generator instead ... here's what I've tried:

After modifying the method:

```
def initialize_dataset(self, tf_record, batch_size):
    dataset = read_tfr(tf_record, self.classes_file, get_feature_map(), self.max_boxes)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=128)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (
        transform_images(x, self.input_shape[0]),
        transform_targets(y, self.anchors, self.masks, self.input_shape[0])))
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
   while True:
        yield image, label
```

and I call `model.fit()` like so:

```
training_size = sum([1 for _ in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(self.train_tf_record)])
history = self.training_model.fit(training_gen,
                                  epochs=epochs,
                                  callbacks=callbacks,
                                  validation_data=valid_gen,
                                  steps_per_epoch=training_size / batch_size)
```

Training freezes after the first epoch:

```
2/45 [>.............................] - ETA: 23s - loss: 9690.3174 - layer_207_output_0_loss: 470.6727 - layer_234_output_1_loss: 1492.7981 - layer_261_output_2_loss: 7715.1030WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time. Check your callbacks.
46/45 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4130.6221 - layer_207_output_0_loss: 95.8419 - layer_234_output_1_loss: 458.6847 - layer_261_output_2_loss: 3564.34792020-04-28 04:37:58,844 session_log.read_tfr +177: INFO     [7901] Read TFRecord: ../Data/TFRecords/beverly_hills_test.tfrecord
```

If I do not specify the `steps_per_epoch`, the epoch continues to run past 45 steps and goes forever(went up to 2000 steps in one of the trials without throwing errors)

So I tried replacing `while True` in the generator with `while start < num_of_steps`, it works and after the first epoch, the model is checkpointing and saved then I get a StopIteration error.

How can I make this work with a generator? I don't want to pass the dataset as a whole to `model.fit` (this works fine until something gets out of memory)

Comment: It looks that `image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(batch_size)))` is depleted. Not sure if it works, but you should keep cycling over the set using `itertools.cycle`

Comment: Thanks, can you show me how to do that exactly? And `next(iter(dataset.take(1)))` works as far as I know otherwise, the loss won't drop as the training progresses, however, show me how it's done

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `read_tfr` is written?

Comment: @bluesummers I edited my question and added `read_tfr()` however it does not have anything to do with the problem, I tested this same code on small datasets(without using a generator) and it works fine.

Comment: The lines `image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(1))); while True: yield image, label` don't really make sense, you will just give the first element repeatedly, like an infinite list of the first element.

Comment: @Cireo I replaced 1 with batch_size, still the same issue, any suggestions on how to replace this faulty line?

Comment: If you can guarantee it is always used in order and completely exhausted (which would be a little surprising to me, but I'm no expert): `while True: yield from dataset` for python 3.  for py2k, `while True: for i in dataset: yield i`

Comment: @Cireo for some reason this won't work and will give some incompatible shapes error

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that you run out of memory due to the initial dataset, so whether you `return iter(dataset)` or `return dataset` that object will be stored in memory once.  I suspect the problem lies elsewhere.  Try looking at your layers

Comment: @Cireo The program works perfectly fine on small datasets, everything works fine, troubles only show up for large datasets. Anyway I'm suspecting there is something else wrong because as you said it does not make sense so I'll be looking closer

Comment: For potential exhaustion issue: replace `image, label = next(iter(dataset.take(1)))` with `iterator= itertools.cycle(dataset.take(1)))` and the output will be `yield next(iterator)`. Not sure if it provides sensible data for training...

Comment: @kate-melnykova That would need experimenting, anyway I already solved the problem which turned out to be something completely different than what I assumed to be a memory problem